# I don't understand the use of the spread operator with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I don't understand the use of the spread operator in the following code :

```
exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
    const itemObject = JSON.parse(req.body.item);
    const item = new Item({
        ...itemObject,
        name: 'test' 
    });
};
```

I tried to write `itemObject` instead of `...itemObject` but it doesn't work. Why do you have to create a copy of the object with spread operator for this to work?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The object that you get from `JSON.parse()` is a plain JavaScript object. Using spread syntax (it's not an operator) copies the *properties* from that object and makes them available to the Item constructor. You thus end up with an Item instance containing the desired properties.

Comment: The spread operator turns `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` into function-like arguments like `1 2 3 4 5 6`. I generally use it to turn array-like objects into arrays. Like `[...document.querySelectorAll('p')]`. If you have any other questions about it, give me a ping.

Comment: @quicVO spread syntax can do that, but in this case it's *not* what's going on. The properties of the decoded object are being copied one-by-one into a new object passed to the Item constructor.

Comment: This is effectively the same as `itemObject.name = 'test'` and then doing `new Item(itemObject)`

Comment: @Pointy, what do you mean? It is doing exactly that because `{}` is a way to create `new Object()`, so if you think of `{}` as a function it is just adding arguments. At least that is how I think of it ;)

Comment: @quicVO But no one other than you thinks of an object literal as being a function with arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you don't spread it you're creating an "itemObject" property and value. You're effectively doing this:

```js
const item = new Item({
  itemObject: itemObject,
  name: 'test'
});
```